# Can't substring multiline content in an element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I have an element with mutli-line content like so:

```
<root>
    <parent>
        <child>first line
            second line

            forth line
        </child>
    </parent>
</root>
```

I'm looking for a way to get only the second line, like so:

```
second line
```

I've tried using a mixture of `substring-before` and `substring-after` looking for `\n` but I get nothing. My idea was to use `substring-before(substring-after(child, '\n'), '\n')`.

Of course, I'm limited to xPath 1.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
normalize-space(substring-before(substring-after(child, '&#10;'), '&#10;'))
```

This is assuming the lines are separated by the line feed character. Otherwise try carriage returns (#13), or both (CRLF).

Comment: According to the XML specification an XML parser [must always normalize newlines to U+000A](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-line-ends).  The only U+000D characters you will see in the XPath data model are those that were there as `&#13;` or `&#xd;` character references in the original document.

Comment: @IanRoberts Thanks, I wasn't aware of that. That's quite useful to know.

Answer (score 2):

> My idea was to use `substring-before(substring-after(child, '\n'), '\n')`.

If the current context node is the `parent` then this approach is correct (if the current context is the `child` element then use `.` instead of `child`).  But `\n` may not be the correct way to represent a newline character.

XPath doesn't itself support the `\n` escape sequence, but it also doesn't consider control characters to be special in string literals, it will happily accept a literal newline character within a quoted string.  So the issue is how to represent a newline in the host language from which you're evaluating the XPath expressions.  If you were evaluating the expression in Java using `javax.xml.xpath` then you *would* need to use `\n`:

```java
xpath.evaluate("substring-before(substring-after(child, '\n'), '\n')", parent);
```

But in XSLT (as you've tagged your question) you use an XML character reference, either decimal or hex:

```
<xsl:value-of
  select="substring-before(substring-after(child, '&#10;'), '&#10;')" />
```

Literal newlines within attribute values are converted to spaces by the XML parser, so you can't do

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring-before(substring-after(child, '
'), '
')" />
```